# What is the subjunctive in Portuguese?

Tags: modo-subjuntivo

While learning Portuguese, I've come across the subjunctive. As it was described to me, it was a "feeling" of uncertainty, or *wishful*.

Is that the true definition? Is there a better way to define it?

Comment: Do you know any French? (Also, the [subjunctive mood is used in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive), as in "I wish I **were**" not "I wish I was", which comes close to the usage in Portuguese, or French.)

Comment: I don't know French, but I do understand the "I wish I *were*" theory. It's been difficult, however, as there's not any extra "helper words" to indicate it - simply your *desire*, I guess.

Comment: "a "feeling" of uncertainty" is probably not the "true definition". Maybe you could ask about good rules-of-thumb for when to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O subjuntivo é usado para situações supostas ou imaginárias, para expressar dúvidas ou ações condicionais.

Suponhamos que termine nosso dinheiro, o que faremos?
*Let's suppose that our money were finished, what will we do?*

Caso venhas, ficarás em minha casa.
*In case you come, you will stay in my house.*

---

**ENGLISH**

The subjunctive is used to alleged or imaginary situations, to express doubts or conditional actions.

*Suponhamos que termine nosso dinheiro, o que faremos?*
Let's suppose that our money were finished, what will we do?

*Caso venhas, ficarás em minha casa.*
In case you come, you shalt be in my house.